# Как обратиться к конкретной строке в таблице бд?

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server

Создал небольшую программу, которая подключается к БД и выводит всю информацию из определённой таблицы.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connStr = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=D:\Pro\wwwww\wwwww\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
    try
    {
        //пробуем подключится
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From Tablica", conn);

        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
        {
            //цикл по всем столбцам полученной в результате запроса таблицы
            for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
            //Вывод названия столбцов
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + dr.GetName(i).ToString().Trim();
            }

            //читаем данные из таблицы
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                //Вывод значений
                textBox1.Text = dr.GetValue(0).ToString().Trim();
                textBox2.Text = dr.GetValue(1).ToString().Trim();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException se)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = se.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

А как я могу получить доступ только к какой-нибудь определённой строке таблицы (на пример ко второй)?

Общая задумка вообще такая, что при запуске программы в textBox`ы выводятся только значения из первой строки (сейчас выводятся все, но т.к. значение постоянно перезаписывается, то видно только последнее), потом я нажимаю кнопку "далее" и в отображаются значения уже второй строки и т.д. Я так понял у меня получился массив (хотя, наверное, коллекция), но как получить доступ к конкретному элементу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From Tablica", conn);` - замени на `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From Tablica Where id=1 ", conn);`
Здесь `id` - имя уникального поля `1` - значение этого поля для строки, которую нужно получить

Comment: Спасибо большое! Только я не очень понял, а как таким образом можно осуществить навигацию по записям? Ведь у меня в кнопке должен быть код перехода на следующую запись. Я написал Where id="+znachid. Но я не могу менять значение переменной znachid в кнопке, возникают проблемы с областью видимости переменной.

Comment: @FaceHoof я никогда не сталкивался с C#, но могу предположить, что кнопка - объект, в который можно добавить поле(свойство), в котором хранить идентификатор текущей записи.